# c# linq to sql iterating through left join results

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
var emp = (from activeWO in context.ActiveWOs
                               join activeWOUpdated in context.ActiveWOUpdatedTimes on activeWO.PW_ID equals activeWOUpdated.PW_ID into dj
                               from activeWOUpdated in dj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               where activeWO.WODC.Contains("IDC") 
                    select new { activeWO.WO_Status,activeWO.PW_ID, activeWO.T_Number, activeWOUpdated.CALCActiveTimeSec });
```

I have both tables mapped out in the .dbml file but as you can see above I am not pulling a table class object just but just 3 columns from 2 tables.

How can iterate through the results of `emp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can iterate through the results of emp?

Simplest would be:

```
foreach(var item in emp)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.WO_Status);
  //other properties
}
```

Comment: @oleksii, I had to, my websocket on proxy is down and I have to refresh to get new questions :)

Comment: @Oliver, just came back from lunch :)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the collection using `foreach`.

```
foreach (var item in emp)
{
    DoSomething(item.WO_Status);
}
```