# linq to sql select as command

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

I have a SQL query similar to this:

```
SELECT 
((dbo.ActiveWO.StartTime*60*60*24) - dbo.ActiveWOUpdatedTimes.ElapsedTime) as TimeLeft
```

How can I insert that into a linq to sql query?

Basically not sure what the syntax is for AS and how to actually write the calculation above in c# query and then I need to orderby TimeLeft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687763/c-sharp-linq-to-sql-iterating-through-left-join-results), I guess you have a query like, below. You can use `select new` to create an [anonymous type object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) and then use `OrderBy` like:

```
var query = (from activeWO in context.ActiveWOs
            join activeWOUpdated in context.ActiveWOUpdatedTimes on activeWO.PW_ID equals activeWOUpdated.PW_ID into dj
            from activeWOUpdated in dj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where activeWO.WODC.Contains("IDC")
            select new 
            {
              TimeLeft = activeWO.StartTime * 60 * 60 * 24 - dj.ElapsedTime
            }).Orderby(r=> r.TimeLeft);
```

Comment: Yup. That's exactly correct. Thanks. Getting used to the linq :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [*anonymous types*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

```
var results = ... //your query
              .Select(a => new 
               {
                  TimeLeft = a.StartTime * 60 * 60 * 24 - a.ElapsedTime
               });
```